# Function returning unexpected values when vectorizing over numpy tuple

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I wanted to take a quick look at the following distribution function and noticed that something is very wrong with the way I'm trying to do that. When applying the function to `x_range`, all values end up being `0`. I am very confused about this and struggle to understand why that would be the case. Am I using numpy wrong in this situation? At least that is the only explanation I have, but I have not been able to find any sort of explanation for why I am seeing these results.

Below is my code.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def F(x):
    return 0 if x <= 0 \
        else .0025 * x if x <= 100 \
        else .25 if x <= 200 \
        else .0025 * x - .25 if x <= 300 \
        else .0025 * x if x <= 400 \
        else 1


x_range = np.linspace(0, 410, 1000)
plt.plot(np.vectorize(F)(x_range))
plt.show()
```

Also, is anyone aware of a more elegant way to simply plot a function over an interval? I am not really a fan of vectorizing the function and applying it to a specially generated array for the mere purpose of plotting. I assume there should be built-in matplotlib functionality to plot a function over some subspace of `R`.

Comment: If you just need a simple plot, you could do `f_range = [F(x) for x in x_range]` followed by `plt.plot(x_range, f_range)`.  Note that your example code is missing the `x_range` as first parameter in `plt.plot()`.  If you need to vectorize your function, you might need a set of nested `np.where()` calls.

Comment: @JohanC - [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is used for a set of nested `np.where` calls.

Comment: `np.vectorize` seems to be simple, but it has several details that casual users ignore.  `matplotlib` is built around the concept of plotting arrays - both for dependent and independent variables.  It doesn't have a "plot a function over subspace" functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [`vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) says:

> The data type of the output of vectorized is determined by calling the function with the first element of the input. This can be avoided by specifying the otypes argument.

Since your first output is an int, it thinks you want integers. If you pass the type of output you want to `otypes` your problem goes away:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def F(x):
    return 0 if x <= 0 \
        else .0025 * x if x <= 100 \
        else .25 if x <= 200 \
        else .0025 * x - .25 if x <= 300 \
        else .0025 * x if x <= 400 \
        else 1


x_range = np.linspace(0, 410, 1000)
plt.plot(np.vectorize(F, otypes=[float])(x_range))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You still need `plt.plot(x_range, np.vectorize(...))` to show the correct values on the x-axis.

Comment: That's a good point @JohanC

Answer (score 2):

maybe changing the numbers in "if statements" from int to float may help:

```
def F(x):
    return 0.0 if x <= 0.0 \
        else 0.0025 * x if x <= 100.0 \
        else 0.25 if x <= 200.0 \
        else 0.0025 * x - 0.25 if x <= 300.0 \
        else 0.0025 * x if x <= 400.0 \
        else 1.0
```

[image]

Comment: I never expected this to be the cause of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You still need to plot using `plt.plot(x_range, np.vectorize(F)(x_range))`. Otherwise the x-axis is shown as numbers from 0 to 1000 instead of 0 to 410.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting `F` to consistently return a float:

```
In [45]: def F(x):
    ...:     return .0 if x <= 0 \
    ...:         else .0025 * x if x <= 100 \
    ...:         else .25 if x <= 200 \
    ...:         else .0025 * x - .25 if x <= 300 \
    ...:         else .0025 * x if x <= 400 \
    ...:         else 1.0
    ...:
```

And a smaller `x`:

```
In [46]: x = np.linspace(0,410,11)
In [47]: x
Out[47]: array([  0.,  41.,  82., 123., 164., 205., 246., 287., 328., 369., 410.])
```

`vectorize` with `otypes`:

```
In [48]: np.vectorize(F,otypes=[float])(x)
Out[48]: 
array([0.    , 0.1025, 0.205 , 0.25  , 0.25  , 0.2625, 0.365 , 0.4675,
       0.82  , 0.9225, 1.0   ])
```

and the same thing using a list comprehension:

```
In [49]: np.array([F(i) for i in x])
Out[49]: 
array([0.    , 0.1025, 0.205 , 0.25  , 0.25  , 0.2625, 0.365 , 0.4675,
       0.82  , 0.9225, 1.0   ])
```

For this small `x` the list comprehension is faster; for your large `x_range`, `vectorize` is faster.

A "truely vectorized" calculation is:

```
def foo(x):
    res = np.zeros(x.shape)
    mask = (x>0) & (x<=100); res[mask] = 0.0025*x[mask]
    mask = (x>100) & (x<=200); res[mask] = .25
    mask = (x>200) & (x<=300); res[mask] = 0.0025*x[mask]-.25
    mask = (x>300) & (x<=400); res[mask] = 0.0025*x[mask]
    mask = (x>400); res[mask] = 1
    return res
```

For my 10 element `x` is is slower, but for the large `x_range` scales much better.